# How can I connect to Server 2008 via ODBC in PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a remote server running IIS7 and SQL Server 2008 which I'm trying to connect to via ODBC in a PHP script:

```
$server = "server_ip";
$database = 'db';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$conn=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( odbc_error(), true));
}
```

But when it runs, I get:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied., SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in X:\server\htdocs\alert-interim\test.php on line 10
Connection could not be established.
08001
```

Also:

- I have TCP/IP enabled under Sql Server Configuration Manager, "SQL Server Network Configuration" -> "Protocols for MSSQL Server"
- My local environment is Windows 7 running XAMPP with PHP 5.4.27
- Port 1433 has been opened in my local firewall

I've been playing around with sqlsrv connections too but I seem to be getting closer with ODBC.  Is there anything else on the server that needs to be set up for ODBC connections or is my connection method faulty?

---

**EDIT**: As per Daan's comment, I tried switching the connection method over to PDO (but using sqlsrv instead as I'm on Windows):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ' in X:\server\htdocs\alert-interim\test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 X:\server\htdocs\alert-interim\test.php(9): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=7...', 'user', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in X:\server\htdocs\alert-interim\test.php on line 9
```

I also turned on Named Pipes in Sql Server Configuration Manager and restarted the service but to no avail.

Comment: try PDO `new PDO("dblib:host=yourhost;dbname=".$db, $user, $pass);`

Comment: Thanks @Daan, I've updated the question based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specific version of this problem was solved with two steps:

1. An entry had to be created in the hosts file.  I'm a little vague on this as it was carried out by a support technician at my webhost and their response was light on details.  At this point I started receiving different error messages in my script which led me to success after #2:
2. I had to give the connecting user `db_owner` role, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOYQv.png) ([this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/) got me on the right track).

Now I can run queries remotely against the DB using the code I originally posted, with the addition of specifying the port:

```
$virtual_dsn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=12.34.56.78,1433;DATABASE=db';
$connection = odbc_connect($virtual_dsn,'user','pass') or die('ODBC Error:: '.odbc_error().' :: '.odbc_errormsg().' :: '.$virtual_dsn);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after adding the port manually! It has to be followed by a comma.

```
$server = "server_ip" . ",1433";
```